# Can't start rails application via docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I tried to build Docker container with Ruby on Rails application and can't do this.

Dockerfile

```
   FROM ruby:2.5.1
   RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

   RUN mkdir /noteapp
   WORKDIR /noteapp

   ADD Gemfile /noteapp/Gemfile
   ADD Gemfile.lock /noteapp/Gemfile.lock

   RUN bundle install

   ADD . /noteapp
   CMD ["rails","server","-b","0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
   version: '2' 
   services:
          db:
     image: postgres
   web: 
     build: .
     command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
     volumes:
       - .:/noteapp
     ports:
       - "3000:3000"
     depends_on:
       - db
```

After running command

```
sudo docker-compose up --build
```

I got the result, [noteapp_web_1 exited with code 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSt9A.png)
After this action I tried to up my docker container and everything was okey, but my application not responding on localhost:3000

When i tried to saw logs(sudo docker logs id), i got the result
[console_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOcOM.png)

But when I tried to connect to my container, I can't do this, and got a error:

```
sudo docker attach ee43805fd6cf
You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first
```

What should i do to run my application?

Update, i used the solution of @Upendra Chahar
And got this problem 
[rails_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spHlH.png)

[rake_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmuCA.png)

After that I fixed this problem and now i'm having problem with postgresql db: 
   [postgresql_db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0888.png)

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to run this command for creating rails project inside in your container.

```
docker-compose run web rails new . --force --database=postgresql
```

After this you need to rebuild the docker image

```
docker-compose build
```

Than change your config/database.yml file

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: db
  username: postgres
  password:
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: noteapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: noteapp_test
```

Than you need to run

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried your solution, but on the last step, when i run docker-compose up --build, i got some troubles with rails, don't know what should i do. @Upendra Chahar, I attached screenshot at the top.

Comment: check your rails version in gemfile

Comment: check your rails version in gemfile and change to gem 'rails', '5.2.0' and also change docker-compose.yml version to version: '3'

Comment: i did it, but docker-compose said to me, that there is no version 3, i don't know why, i tried ti research, because the third version is present

Comment: K... But u need to check your rails version in gemfile

Comment: Put these lines in your gemfile:-  source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '5.2.0'

Comment: ahaha, i did it and got a new problem with rake 12.3.1

Comment: i attached it in description of problem

Comment: Your app directory is created or not ... Means rails project files ... Than remove everything inside your gemfile.lock and rebuild again

Comment: Rails directory have been created with files, etc. I removed Gemfile.lock and rebuilt(via command docker-compose up --build) and got error with rails again, when I opened Gemfile.lock it was empty.(

Comment: Remove everything and only took Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml file, Gemfile and Gemfile.lock where Gemfile content should be:-    source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '5.2.0'

Comment: Start process from this docker-compose run web rails new . --force --database=postgresql

Comment: I did all steps again and got error with rake 12.3.1, I'm crying. Don't know what to do

Comment: I fixed this problem and got a problem with postgresql db. I attached screen at the topic

Comment: hey u need to run this command... docker-compose run web bundle exec rails db:create RAILS_ENV=development

Comment: thank you so much) Everything is clear, nice to meet you, can you give me your contacts, like email or smth else to communicate with you?

Comment: If my solution is worked for you than please accept my answer. my email id is upendragcet@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

in Dockerfile

```
   FROM ruby:2.5.1
   RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

   RUN mkdir /noteapp
   WORKDIR /noteapp

   ADD Gemfile /noteapp/Gemfile

   RUN bundle install

   ADD . /noteapp
   CMD ["rails","server","-b","0.0.0.0"]
```

Remove this  ADD Gemfile.lock /noteapp/Gemfile.lock 
add this  CMD ["rails","server","-b","0.0.0.0"]

in docker-compose

```
version: '2' 
services: 
   db:
     image: postgres
   web: 
     build: .
     volumes:
       - .:/noteapp
     ports:
       - "3000:3000"
     depends_on:
       - db
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, but your solution doesn't work for me. I updated description of my question, what I tried to do and what was the result. @Gioggi

Answer (score 0):

add tty and stdin_open options in your docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2' 
services:
   db:
      image: postgres
   web: 
      build: .
      stdin_open: true
      tty: true
      command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
      volumes:
        - .:/noteapp
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
      depends_on:
        - db
```

then run

```
docker-compose build
```

and finally you can run

```
docker-compose up
```

or in dettached mode

```
docker-compose up -d
```